# load an already written GTK python codes into a GUI designer

Tags: python, gtk

I want to change the interface of a written application. this application is written in python and GTK . I don't want to change the codes manually by myself but although  I need an interface designer so I can import this application to it and the graphically  apply my intended changes to it . I tried Glade and QTdesigner but they produce .ui file and I couldn't find a tool to convert back a .ui file to python code. plus that the don't open python files directly and didn't have import options. 
any solution will be appreciated. 
thanks

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gtkparasite/issues/detail?id=9

Comment: thanks but can you say how to apply this patch. I already installed galde.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the application.

If the application uses `*.glade` or `*.ui` files you can - depending on how well it is designed re-arrange certain elements and swap out container types.

If there are no such files, you are out of luck. Then the ui is "hard"-coded (as hard as python code can get..) and you have to modify the widget hirarchy by modifying python code yourself.

There is no such editor being able to extract a layout/ui file from code itself.

---

gtkinspector or formerly known as gtkparasite can modify properties of widgets on the fly but nothing that really modifies the python code of the running application. They sneak around the application code and modify the widget tree from back behind through means of the gtk module lib interface (correct me if I am wrong here, not totally sure).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Glade had code generation features removed years ago, because that leads to unmaintainable code when it's patched by hand after generation, to add the program's internal logic. So either you:

- use Glade to generate a ui file, and have to change the python code anyway to use it
- or you'll have manually write some code to change the user interface

In either way, you'll have some code to write. If you have lots of changes in the user interface, then convert your program to use Glade ui files. It will take some time, but changes will be easier afterwards. If you only have a couple of changes to do, just do them in the code, it will be faster to do.

Comment: thanks but how can I convert my program to use glade files? It's a bunch of python files which contain a hierarchy of gtk libraries.

Comment: As drahn told you, [gtk-inspector](http://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/11/23/gtk-inspector-update/) is a tool that wan help you to see how the interface is created. You need to create a new project in Glade, reproduce the interface, and then use that change your python code logic so that it uses the glade objects instead of those created by hand in the code. See this tutorial: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builder.html